# Escaping quotes when writing to a file

Tags: external-files, quotation

When using quotes as part of strings one often needs to escape the quotes. I now have a string `My nice title` stored in `\mytitle` and I want to write, from LaTeX, a JSON file which reads `{title: "My nice title"}`. This works as in the book.

However, when the title contains a quote, such as `The case "Johnny R." is cool.` then I have to escape the quotes in the title, as in `{title: "The case \"Johnny R.\" is cool."}`.

All Javascript libraries have functions which do this automagically. But how would I do such a quote escapement from LaTeX?

Comment: using " to insert quotes in latex is wrong. It doesn't give the right quote symbols.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually I am writing a JSON file and I need exactly a " there. I am not writing a Latex file as in "PDF".

Comment: But why don't you input the quotes directly correctly? The input of  `The case "Johnny R." is cool` is of no use in latex as it gives the wrong quotes, and it is of no use in JSON as the encoding is wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe I misunderstand your "no use in latex". My document is beamer and with the fonts I use the " is perfectly fine for me although it does not produce the 66 99 scheme publishers usually require. If I move to a different documentclass, however, I realize this might, then, become a necessity, though.

Comment: that is what I mean. It is wrong in latex, and if you would use proper latex input, e.g. `\enquote{Jonny R.}` it would be easy to redefine it so that it writes a correct JSON to a file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer NOW I got it. :-). Cool idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LuaTeX, you can use the bundled `\luaescapestring` function. Otherwise, you can try the `\myescapestring` function implemented with LaTeX3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\myescapestring}[1]{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {"} {\u{c_backslash_str}"} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\par\luaescapestring{this is "a string"}
\par\myescapestring{this is "a string"}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the idea but I have to write this into an external JSON file and not produce a PDF from it. If I \immediate\write the result of \myescapestring I get some unreadable gibberish in the written file.