# Writing properly escaped strings to a file

Tags: write, write-file

I have to write a properly (as in JSON or Javascript) escaped string to a file.

My minimal example is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begingroup
\catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12
\gdef\wbgroup<{>
\gdef\wegroup<}>
\endgroup

\def\mytitle{This is a "title" for me}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\jsonwrite
\immediate\openout\jsonwrite=file.json
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{\wbgroup}
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{  title: "\mytitle"}
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{\wegroup}
\end{document}
```

What I get is a file.json with

```
{
 title: "This is a "title" for me"
}
```

whereas what I need is the internal quotes escaped as in

```
{
 title: "This is a \"title\" for me"
}
```

I have the suggestion [Escaping quotes when writing to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571030/196228) but if I do this

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begingroup
\catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12
\gdef\wbgroup<{>
\gdef\wegroup<}>
\endgroup

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\myescapestring}[1]{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {"} {\u{c_backslash_str}"} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mytitle{This is a "title" for me}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\jsonwrite
\immediate\openout\jsonwrite=file.json
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{\wbgroup}
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{  title: "\myescapestring\mytitle"}
\immediate\write\jsonwrite{\wegroup}
\end{document}
```

I get an even much worse result, namely

```
{
 title: "\tl_set:Nn {This is a "title" for me}\regex_replace_all:nnN {"}{\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {c_backslash_str\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\let \begingroup \endgroup \relax \let \ignorespaces \relax \accent 8 c_backslash_str\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor "}"
}
```

I am stuck with PDFLaTeX and cannot use LUATex, since I am using many features of PDFLaTeX in other parts of my original document.

So essentially I am looking for a stringEscape function for Javascript in PDFTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the escaping prior to writing, because it is not an expandable operation.

Without knowing more details on what you want to write out, a possible solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\jsonwrite}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = file name,
  % #2 = initial part
  % #3 = middle part
  % #4 = final part
  \nkiad_jsonwrite:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\iow_new:N \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow
\tl_new:N \l__nkiad_jsonwrite_item_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nkiad_jsonwrite:nnnn
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow { #1 }
  \iow_now:Nx \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow { \c_left_brace_str }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__nkiad_jsonwrite_item_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \" } { \cO\\ \" } \l__nkiad_jsonwrite_item_tl
  \iow_now:Nx \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow
   {
    #2 % initial part
    \l__nkiad_jsonwrite_item_tl % middle part
    #4 % final part
   }
  \iow_now:Nx \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow { \c_right_brace_str }
  \iow_close:N \g__nkiad_jsonwrite_iow
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mytitle{This is a "title" for me}

\begin{document}

\jsonwrite{\jobname.json}{  title: "}{\mytitle}{"}

\end{document}
```

We need to distinguish between quotes to be escaped (those contained in `\mytitle`) and those that shouldn't be.